# Android Add many Imageview by code

Tags: android, layout, imageview, drawable

I would like to create a layout with many ImageView on it.

It should be an array of 10 pictures by 15 pictures. There is only 5 differents picture but I need to place them many time on this array.

Something like that but in 10 * 15 :

http://blazinggames.com/brain/puzzle/screenshots/cc.gif

So far, I am using a linear layout ( not sure it is the best choice Oo ) and I have this :

[image]

unsing this code :

```
LinearLayout linearLayout= new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
       LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
       LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linearLayout.addView(imageView);
setContentView(linearLayout);
```

And I set an imageview1, imageview2, ... Each one with one of the 5 drawable I want ...

I know ! It is not the good way to code this ! It could work but it is very very long !

That is why I am here ^^

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use custom grid view.

Comment: You could have used a for loop to place your image view if the image chosen depends on the position. If this is not the case, so you have no way out but to manually code each.

Comment: Thanks guys but I dont know how to create a custom GridView neither to use a loop to set different drawable for different imageview, can you help me a little bit more ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to make a gridview ! Thanks !